# Javascript | problem getting the extension of uploaded file on device

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, input, device

i'm having a problem with the validation of uploaded file in a form.

```
   var input = event.target.files[0].name;

   var allowedExtensions = /(\.mp3|\.wav|\.aiff|\.aac|\.wma)$/i;

   if(allowedExtensions.exec(input)){
     //success 
   }else{
     //wrong
   }

   if ((input.files[0].size/1024/1024) > 100){
     //wrong
   }
```

On desktop this code works fine, but on device it seems like it doesn't get the extension of the file, just the name. So i can't validate it.

I've tried also getting the file with:

```
  var input = document.getElementById('file');
```

and also with JQuery, but same thing.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try splitting the file name using `.` as the separator. Math the last element of the resulting array with your allowed extensions.

Comment: @ShivamKumar thanks for answering, if i alert the input variable, it doesn't even show the extension, only the name of the file.

Comment: `event.target.files[0].name` is different on every browser

Comment: @freedomn-m i've tried also with var input = document.getElementById('file') and it's the same thing.

Comment: I tried it in my browser and it shows the file extension, try using `event.target.value`, it shows the full path of the first selected file.